# Unable to read cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, cookies, wss

I am currently using a WSS 3.0 Web Part (C#) for creating a cookie.

I have a link button in my Sharepoint site which has an event that calls an encryption method and then stores the encrypted value in the Cookie. After creating the cookie, I am redirecting the user to a new URL which opens in a new window.

The cookie creation is successful. I was able to store my desired value and the domain that it gets is the one of where the link button is located.

What I want to do is to open the cookie in the newly opened window but when I try to use HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieName"] I always get a null.

Can anyone help me with this issue ? I've been working on this for a couple of days now. I believe that there is an issue here regarding domains but I can't figure out the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would start troubleshooting this by using browser developer tools (e.g. F12 in IE) to ensure that the cookies are actually being saved on the client - yes? Then :-

Is the new window opening with a URL that has a domain the same as the orig URL?

e.g. 
   #1 http://site.yourdomain.com/page1
   #2 http://site.yourdomain.com/page2

If not then site1 can't read site2's cookies.

You also need to do some extra stuff to share across sub-domains.

[MSDN - ASP.NET Cookies Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ryan. I was able to research about what i am doing right now and i have figured out that what i'm trying to do is impossible since it is a cross-domain cookie.

Comment: I have decided to use POST method instead of making use of cookies